# AWS s3 bucket effective permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions, bucket

Is there an easy way to see what are the effective access permissions for a specific bucket? To be more specific about the environment, access to buckets is granted through identity policies, there are more than 170 IAM roles and users and 1000+ policies (not all of them are attached to IAM role or user). I need to see who has the s3:GetObject, s3:PutObject and s3:DeleteObject permission on a specific bucket. Is there some tool that can give me that kind of report? I can write a script that goes through all roles, policies attached to them, pulls out statements that contain specific bucket and then I can cross reference allows and denys, but I'm sure there is some smarter way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any better way than you described. You can export your IAM settings (unless you already have them in CloudFormation or CDK scripts) as described at https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/a-simple-way-to-export-your-iam-settings/.

Then you can scan (manually or programatically) for policies of interest and to what users or roles are they attached.

Answer (score 1):

From [Using Access Analyzer for S3 - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/access-analyzer.html):

> **Access Analyzer for S3** alerts you to S3 buckets that are configured to allow access to anyone on the internet or other AWS accounts, including AWS accounts outside of your organization. For each public or shared bucket, you receive findings into the source and level of public or shared access. For example, Access Analyzer for S3 might show that a bucket has read or write access provided through a bucket access control list (ACL), a bucket policy, or an access point policy. Armed with this knowledge, you can take immediate and precise corrective action to restore your bucket access to what you intended.